# How to hide the implementation file in static library

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I am developing one static library and using that .a file and .h files in my application.And i put the breakpoints in static library .m file.And if i run my application then application stop at that break point.SO how to avoid that break points in my application.

Comment: Have you created your own custom static library ?

Comment: now whats the problem? Go to your custom library and from implementation file remove the breakpoints. And then include your updated library.framework file in your working application...it will work...

Comment: It's simple; disable the breakpoints.